# Getting empty value in Spring post mapping

Tags: java, spring, post, thymeleaf

When the browser sends a POST request to this mapping, the parameter it is supposed to send is empty.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/}">
    <input type="search" name="ime-grada" placeholder="ime grada">
</form>
```

POST mapping:

```
@Controller
public class Post implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static String slikaUrl = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/";

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String vremePost(Model model, String imeGrada) {
        System.out.println("post " + imeGrada); // prints null
        imeGrada = "Beograd"; // hardcoded for testing
        ArrayList<Root> gradovi = new ArrayList<Root>();
        gradovi = PodaciOVremenu.podaciOVremenu(imeGrada);
        model.addAttribute("gradovi", gradovi);
        model.addAttribute("slikaUrl", slikaUrl);
        return Get.vremeGet(model, gradovi);
    }

}
```

GET Mapping - Get.vremeGet()

```
@Controller
public class Get implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static String slikaUrl = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/";

    @GetMapping("/")
    public static String vremeGet(Model model, ArrayList<Root> gradovi) {
        if (gradovi.size() == 0) {
            gradovi = PodaciOVremenu.podaciOVremenu(null);
        }
        model.addAttribute("gradovi", gradovi);
        model.addAttribute("slikaUrl", slikaUrl);
        return "vreme";
    }
}
```

It is expected that the print statement print the parameter sent by the POST request,
but it prints null instead.
I'm using Java 15, Spring 2.4.3, Thymeleaf 3.0.12.RELEASE

Comment: Can you show the Get.vremeGet() method?

Comment: @MorBlau Thank you for responding. I edited my question to show the Get.vremeGet() method.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the little error that crept up on me. In the HTML the name of the variable is ime-grada, while on the corresponding server mapping it is imeGrada.